# In constructor ‘Player::Player()’: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants

I have this line in my Blackjack default constructor.

```
m_players[0].SetPlayerName("Jane");
```

This uses a setter in my Player class to set the player's name as Jane.

My Player constructor is this.

```
Player::Player()
{
  Player player;
  player.m_funds = 0;
  player.m_name = "";
  player.m_bet = 0;
  player.m_busted = false;
}
```

And, for more information, my SetPlayerName method is this.

```
void Player::SetPlayerName(char name)
{
  m_name = name;
}
```

How do I fix this conversion error? I am just trying to set the player's name to be a char. Thanks!

I am just trying to setup a default constructor with one player, Jane.

Comment: A string literal is not a char, it will convert to a pointer in this context, which is what the error is telling you. Why do you expect this to work?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what a char is? Because chars are not what you want here. Try a string.

Comment: Pls provide the class declaration.

Comment: Also, your constructor is wrong. It shouldn't be declaring and constructing a `Player player`; it's already running in the context of a Player, and it should be initializing the state of `this`.

Comment: You may want to review what chars are. Chars represent *1* character. You have 4 (and a null terminator).

Comment: You probably want a char array like `char name[BUFFER_SIZE]`

Comment: It seems like you're attempting something significantly beyond your capabilities. There are errors all over the place in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A String literal (something like `"Foobar"` is of type `const char[N]` where `N` is the amount of characters + 1 (for the null terminator), meaning array of `N` `char`.

Your variable `m_name` seems to be of type `char` which is a single char.

There is no way to convert an array of `const char[N]` to `char`. What you really want is `m_name` to be of type `std::string` or possibly `const char*`.

Why `const char*`? A `const char[N]` decays to a `const char*` and can point to a literal of any size.

Comment: Well the error actually says `char`, so unless the OP copied the error wrong this is not the case.

Comment: Ah, OP knows less about C++ than I thought.